# Reading streams from image on a web page in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, stream, iostream

I have an image bound in the image control in my asp.net website.

I am using C# to develop it. Below the code to bind the image.

```
 byte[] imageBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("filepath");
 string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
 this.testImage.Src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + base64String;
```

Now I want to take the streams from that image control (testImage) in another event.
I dont want to save the image in any server path.

How Can I do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
Image img = Image.FromStream(webClient.OpenRead(path));
webClient.Dispose();
```

That applies only if the image is not a file on your hard disk.

And if the image is on the hard disk, this should do it:

```
Image img = Image.FromFile(path);
```